# Where Does the "info - socket.io started" come from?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'd like to know where does the "info  - socket.io started" part come from? I would like to see it on node prompt.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking. It comes from socket.io module. What do you exactly need to know about it?

Comment: Well, here's exactly what I'd like to know http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30435656/info-socket-io-started-missing